# How can I contribute to Doctrine documentation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've been using Doctrine since a long time, and always felt the documentation is one its weakest spot. I've no problems myself looking in stackoverflow, irc and even looking at the code directly, but, my coworkers tend to ask me a lot just because the documentation isn't there or is to complicated or vague.

Is there a way I can contribute to Doctrine documentation, btw I haven't found nothing about that in the site, hence this question :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is in the [git repository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2) over at github.  Fork the repo, make changes/additions, and send pull requests.